# How do i insert an image into Rectangle

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build eBay system listing on mobile app but I can't figure out how they managed to insert an image into the `Rectangle`. clipshape with RoundedRectangle modifier doesn't give me the Rectangle shape and aspect ratio ... please advise.

I just can't figure out how to do it, spent 2 hours, no joy.

[Xcode screenshot with preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is14j.jpg)

```swift
ScrollView {
            
            VStack {
                
                Divider()
                   
                
                HStack {
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 180)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.continuous/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/), style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/FillStyle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Iveco Daily 2.3 XLWB Automatic with Penumatic suspension")
                            .font(.title3)
                        Text("Pre-owned")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                        Text("£9,400.00")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text("London")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                
                Divider()
                    
            }
        }
        .contentMargins(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an image, then replace `Rectangle()` with
`Image(image).resizable()`

Here is my full test code to show an Image clipped to a RoundedRectangle as the Rectangle was:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let image = "globe" // <--- for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Image(systemName: image) // <--- for testing
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 180)
                            .background(Color.cyan)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Iveco Daily 2.3 XLWB Automatic with Penumatic suspension")
                            .font(.title3)
                        Text("Pre-owned")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                        Text("£9,400.00")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text("London")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 2)
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not the same dimensions if I replace Rectangle() with Image(image).resizable().

Comment: updated my answer with the code I used to test it. If you want other size/dimensions adjust as required. The Image is exactly the same size as the Rectangle in my code.

Comment: wow thanks... you are a star thank you a lot buddy

Comment: if my answer helped, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

Comment: @EastAnglian94 if workingdog really helped you, you should also up-vote their answer. That's not required on SO like accepting the best correct answer, but it shows gratitude. (Voted)